# What's the difference when defining var as 0.5 compared to .5?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious, I have programmed JavaScript already few years but sometimes I get confused when I see the following variable declarations: (ofc. those could be any other numbers as well).

```
var exampleOne = 0.5;
var exampleTwo = .5;
```

What is the difference between these two, or is there any? Are there some sort of hidden benefits which I clearly don't understand?

Comment: Some people find the first version easier to read, but there's no difference to the computer.

Comment: Relevant section in the spec: http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.3 (DecimalLiteral)

Comment: The difference is one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

The [Numeric Literals](http://es5.github.io/#B.1.1) are parsed equivalently - that is, both `0.5` and `.5` (as would `.50`) represent the *same* number. (Unlike most other languages, JavaScript has only one kind of number.)

*I* prefer to always include the [optional] leading 0 before the decimal.

Comment: I am pretty sure someone will come and find a difference, they always do :)

Comment: Putting aside the benefits of gzip, do you suppose variable declarations without the leading zero might benefit those on slower connections?

Comment: @JackPattishallJr.: even on a 14.4k modem, the difference would be unnoticeable even if you did that 1000 times.

Comment: Just like how apparently yoda logic compresses better.

Comment: @dandavis - I'm thinking more along the lines of mobile, where bandwidth (and more importantly latency hits) might affect things.. I do agree with you though - unless working with a large set of data, the differences between declaring a var with leading zeroes would probably be unnoticeable. That's before gzip...

Comment: even without gzip, no telco or mobile provider is going to send out a bunch of repetition like that. ever notice how a 10mb log file downloads faster over ftp than a 10meg MP3? the dev is not the only one compressing. some switches and routers have it built in.

Comment: Thanks. So I think it is more or less cosmetic, however if time is money, declaring variable as .5 costs more ;) kidding.. thnx!

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. In this context, one byte makes *no* difference in terms of data-transmission or parsing costs. Honest :)

Comment: Also don't forget about energy costs associated with development. `.5` requires less energy than `0.5` IF your text editor has a black background. Vice versa for white background.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3):

`0.5` matches the rule *DecimalLiteral :: DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits* which is evaluated as (MV means *mathematical value*):

> The MV of *DecimalLiteral :: DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits* is the MV of *DecimalIntegerLiteral* plus (the MV of *DecimalDigits* times 10<sup>–n</sup>), where *n* is the number of characters in *DecimalDigits*.

`.5` matches the rule *DecimalLiteral :: . DecimalDigits* which is evaluated as

> The MV of *DecimalLiteral :: . DecimalDigits* is the MV of *DecimalDigits* times 10<sup>–n</sup>, where *n* is the number of characters in *DecimalDigits*.

So you can see that the only difference is that the value of the digits preceding the `.` are added to the final value. And adding `0` to a value doesn't change the value.

Comment: +1 it makes sense.. thnx. I can feel the growing wisdom inside me. :D